# css image sprite to javascript on mouse function

Tags: javascript, css

I am using CSS sprite by using div tags.But in the below code there is JavaScript and I can't keep sprite to that.Is it possible to keep the CSS sprite to the below code? Image is in onmouseover function.

```
<a href="" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image52','','social-rss-h.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()">
```

Comment: Why not use sprite with CSS and a element id/class?

Comment: how to pass the image background position to onmouse event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a class/id for links you want to sprite (you can add sprite to links, but, for organization, I prefer classes/id)

```
a.sprite {
    background-image: url(images/menu.gif);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a.sprite:hover {
    background-position: 0 -60px 
}


<a class="sprite" href="" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image52','','social-rss-h.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()">
```